# How to define unique indexes when softDeletes is enabled

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4

Will Laravel 4.1 manage the creation of a unique index(where deleted_at = null) by itself when softDeletes?

Is the approach below correct? Or is it going to mix in already deleted records?

```
Schema::create('example', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('example')->unsigned()->unique(); //?????
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

The database is mysql, but if there's certain solutions for other DB:s, you can provide them as well. However, it should be done within the laravel framework! A uniform solution that works with all dbs that laravel officially supports is appreciated.

**Update**
It seems like this approach does not work, since it just ignores the softDeletes() option.

So proposed solution

```
Schema::create('exampe', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('example')->unsigned();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->unique('example', 'deleted_at');
});
```

Problem is that there can potentially be two exactly similar timestamps at the deleted_at column.

What I actually need is a where-condition.

```
$table->unique('example', array('where', 'deleted_at', '=', null));
```

or

```
$table->integer('example')->unsigned()->unique()->where('deleted_at', '=', null)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend making a two-column UNIQUE constraint over the column you want to be unique (`example`) and a dummy column for instance called `is_live`. This column is always '1' when the row is *not* soft-deleted. When you soft-delete a row, set `is_live=NULL`.

The reason is related to the way "uniqueness" is defined. **Unique constraints allow any number of rows that have a NULL value.** This is because NULL is not equal to NULL in SQL, so therefore two NULLs count as "not the same".

For multi-column unique keys, if *any* column is NULL, the whole set of columns in the unique key behaves as if it's not the same as any other row. Therefore you can have any number of rows that have one column of the unique key the same, as long as the other column in the unique key is NULL.

```
create table example (
  id serial primary key,
  example int unsigned not null,
  is_live tinyint default 1,
  unique key (example, is_live)
);
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d1e4d/1

PS: The direct answer to your question, about implementing a condition for indexes in MySQL, is that MySQL doesn't support this. Databases that do support partial indexes include:

- PostgreSQL (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html)
- Microsoft SQL Server (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using `$table->softDeletes()` doesn't change how the `Schema` sets `unique` indexes. In your example only the `example` column will be unique.

If you want to have multiple columns in your `unique` index just run `$table->unique(['column1', 'column2'])`.

To set `unique` index you either use it on a chain, like `$table->integer('example')->unique()` or have it on a new row, like I wrote above.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. Why have $table->unique(['column', 'deleted_at']); for all indexes and assuming all active indexes is null and that all timestamps will be unique(they may not). Therefore a good solution would be to make something like: $table->integer('example')->unsigned()->unique()->where('deleted_at', '=', null) if you know what I mean.

Comment: The two are not the same, 1st `unique(['col1','col2'...])` creates unique composite index, while 2nd `('example')->unique();` separate unique indexes on each field.

Comment: Neither of these suggestions will solve actual the problem :) I need a condition!

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. Using 2 columns as unique, after soft delete I can't create another row with same unique data.
What I want is using Blueprint table object achieve (not RAW query) that SQL:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test ON test_table USING btree (test_id, user_id) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;`

But Blueprint and Fluent object dont have any where method.

Comment: This solution only fits Postgres.